# Visual Studio TypeScript - Out of Stack Space

Tags: stack-overflow, typescript1.4

We're using VS 2013 with TypeScript 1.4 and have started getting the following 'out of stack space' error during transpiling:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>VSTSC : tsc.js(15645, 21) JavaScript runtime error : Out of stack space
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There seems to be very few other references to this error and the error message does not give us much to go on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be exactly what the message indicates. We apparently had too many string constants. Once we removed those the 'out of stack space' stopped occurring.